# Customizing week number in R shiny

Tags: shiny

I am trying to build a shiny application where the output will say "The current week is x" where x is the week number. The problem in this case is my year starts on 3/30/2014 and I have defined a week to be  from Sunday to Saturday which I am unable code properly resulting in erroneous output. I am attaching the code below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            dateInput('Start_Date',label = "Choose Date",value = Sys.Date())
            ),
        mainPanel(
            textOutput("text1")
            ),
          )
        ))
    server.R
    library(shiny)
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
              output$text1<-renderText({
                      paste("The current week is",ceiling(abs(difftime(as.Date("3/30/2014","%m/%d/%y"),as.Date(input$Start_Date),by="weeks"))/7))
    })
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had small problem with formatting. I have added the start the day from which the year start too (so if you want your count to start from Sunday you can specify) so you can change it if you want.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateInput('Year_starts',label = "Count From",value = as.Date("2014/03/30")),
      dateInput('Start_Date',label = "Choose Date",value = Sys.Date())
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text1")
    ),
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$text1<-renderText({
    dates <- seq(input$Year_starts, as.Date(input$Start_Date), by = "weeks")
    length(dates)-1
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```